DPY-3008: unsupported in-band notification with error number 2396
I run a SQL query with a python script. i use python-oracledb library. same script works for other queries without error. i run query on Toad. there is no problem or error. i check the search engines for error message. i couldn't find a solution.
any ideas?

That error indicates that your session has exceeded the maximum idle time allowed by your connection and that you need to reconnect. The thin driver needs to be enhanced to support that in-band notification. You can log an issue: https://github.com/oracle/python-oracledb/issues

A fix has been identified by @anthony and will be in the next release of python-oracledb (version 2.4).  Note it just gives you a clearer error message: ""the database closed the connection because the connection's idle time has been exceeded".  You still need to reconnect.  For some applications, using a connection pool is a good idea because it can automatically reconnect.

In My case we were using the latest version of oracledb 2.4.0 with pip package which was causing this issue so instead of using this latest version I reverted back to the old version 2.2.1 in which we can connect without any issues.
If we are making use of requirments.txt file then use specify the version as well oracledb==2.2.1 to install the older version instead of the latest version.

The fix to the first issue caused the one you are experiencing. It has already been addressed as well.
